# Angular http.get - Transforming result

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-http

Angular 8

I have a http.get :

```
this.http.get("https://BahaiPrayers.net/api/prayer/Languages")
  .subscribe(data => {
       //return a different object
  });
```

The json from the server looks like this:

```
{
 Id: 1,
 Name: "English",
},....
```

I need the http.get to transform the data into my typescript array of this class:

```
 export class Language {
      languageId: number;
      englishName: string;
  }
```

Is there a way to have the http.Get convert to my object?

Comment: Please post the content of the http.get data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this in a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LanguageService {

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    getLanguages(): Observable<Language[]> {
        return this.httpClient.get<any[]>('https://BahaiPrayers.net/api/prayer/Languages')
        .pipe(
            //** This is where the tranformation happens
            map(lanuages => lanuages.map(language => (
               { languageId: language.Id, englishName: language.Name })))
            //** change language.Name to language.English 
            //** if you need the English name of the language 
        );
    }
}

export class Language {
    languageId: number;
    englishName: string;
}
```

Then call `getLanguage()` from a component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LanguageService, Language } from '../services/language.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-language',
    templateUrl: './language.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./language.component.css']
})
export class LanguageComponent implements OnInit {
    languages: Language[];

    constructor(private languageService: LanguageService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.languageService.getLanguages().subscribe(
            languages => this.languages = languages);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since recent Angular version if your Object share the same attributes than your JSON it's not required anymore to map the result (it'll be done automatically)  :

```
export class Language {
  Id: number;
  Name: string;
}
...
```

Then in a service :

```
getLanguages(): Observable<Language[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Language[]>('https://BahaiPrayers.net/api/prayer/Languages');
}
```